# User's activity stream on different page

Tags: 2010, activity-feed

I want to be able to display the top 3-5 updates from the user's MySite 'Whats new' on the intranet home page, this currently exists as a different web application but on the same farm.

I've not been able to find a web part either downloadable or OOTB and can't replicate this with the RSS viewer as we are not using kerberos.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this by using a much simpler method with no coding at all:

- Export the 'Whats new' web part from the mysites home page
- Upload to site collection in question, in my case intranet site
- Add web part to page.
- Edit web part to display amount of updates, defaults to 20 but I changed this to 3

Once this part is added to the page you do get the links and header at the top which I didn't want to display so I hid the element through CSS (surprisingly there is only one - ".ms-newsfeedlinksection"

- Claim the credit for creating the web part from scratch